# Odoo 10 : How to make separate address lines in contact form view?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

My address appears like this :

[image]

and I want the address to appear it different lines like this :

laubachstr.1

laubastr.2

belrin

hanburg

12345

Germany

I tried this method but didnt work :

https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-can-i-change-address-format-in-customer-form-view-17056

Below is my format :

```
%(street)s

%(street2)s

%(city)s

%(state_id)s

%(zip)s 

%(country_id)s
```

How to make this address data appear in different lines??

**Info** : My address field in  form view is :

```
<div>
                                                    <div class="o_address_format" name="div_address">
                                                        <field name="street" placeholder="Street..." class="o_address_street"/>
                                                        <field name="street2" placeholder="Street 2..." class="o_address_street"/>
                                                        <field name="city" placeholder="City" class="o_address_city"/>
                                                        <field name="state_id" class="o_address_state" placeholder="State" options="{&quot;no_open&quot;: True}" context="{'country_id': country_id, 'zip': zip}"/>
                                                        <field name="zip" placeholder="ZIP" class="o_address_zip"/>
                                                        <field name="country_id" placeholder="Country" class="o_address_country" options="{&quot;no_open&quot;: True, &quot;no_create&quot;: True}"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your browser to inspect the generated HTML code for the form view, you'll find that the `city, state_id` and `zip` fields have an `o_field_widget` class which, in turn, has a `display: block-inline`, but you want it to be `display: block`.

So, assuming you have a module named `my_module`, one solution is as follows:

1. Create a new CSS class. I added it to `my_module/static/src/less/style.less`

   ```
   .my_display_block {
     display: block !important;
   }
   ```
2. Add your style file to your backend assets. I added it to `my_module/templates/assets.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <odoo>
       <data>
           <template id="assets_backend" name="my module backend assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
               <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
                   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my_module/static/src/less/style.less"/>
               </xpath>
           </template>
       </data>
   </odoo>
   ```
3. Modify your contact form. I added the following to `my_module/views/res_partner.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <odoo>
     <data>
       <record id="address_in_block_form" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">Display address in block style
         <field name="model">res.partner
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='city']" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="class" add="my_display_block" separator=" "/>
           </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='state_id']" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="class" add="my_display_block" separator=" "/>
           </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='zip']" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="class" add="my_display_block" separator=" "/>
           </xpath>
         </field>
       </record>
     </data>
   </odoo>
   ```
4. Finally, make sure your templates and views are called from the `__manifest__.py`

   ```
       'data': [
           'templates/assets.xml',
           'views/res_partner.xml',
           # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
       ],
   ```

You can clone a minimal module with all the above from `https://github.com/AdanCortes/stackoverflow/tree/q52668609`

Answer (score 0):

Remove div from fields group and class="o_address_street" from your fields. This may give you expected result.